# If && not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I have looked at every similar question i can find but i am scratching to work out why my if && stament isn't working.

```
if ((cEventStatus) && (ddayDif = 0)) {
        NSLog(@"upDateCountersWorking");
        [self upDateCountersWorking];

}else if ((cEventStatus) && (ddayDif > 0 )){
    NSLog(@"currentlyWorkingAddDays");
    [self currentlyWorkingAddDays:&ddayDif];

}else if ((!cEventStatus) && (ddayDif = 0)){
     NSLog(@"upDateCountersResting");
    [self upDateCountersResting];

}else if ((!cEventStatus) && (ddayDif > 0)){
    NSLog(@"currentlyRestingAddDays");
    [self currentlyRestingAddDays:&ddayDif];   
}else{
    NSLog(@"final else");
}
```

I originally didn't have enough () around each statement and only & instead of &&, from the other questions i found i made the changes to come to the above code. But still no success.

In desperation i have added the following code to confirm the variables and am getting the expected results.

```
if (cEventStatus) {
    NSLog(@"YES status");
}else{
    NSLog(@"NO status");
}

if (ddayDif > 0) {
    NSLog(@"greater than 0");
}else{
   NSLog(@"less than 0");
}
```

But the if else never gives the expected result, always falls to the final else regardless of variable values.

I am sure this will be a simple issue but any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your first statement, you need `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with objective-c, but the `ddayDif = 0` looks suspicious to me. I'm used to that meaning an *assignment* rather than a *comparison*, which would explain why `if(ddayDif > 0)` is never true. **Edit:** @Avi beat me to it for a few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
if ((cEventStatus) && (ddayDif = 0)) {
```

isn't checking the value of `ddayDif`, it's setting it (to zero) - which isn't what you want.

In each of your checks you should be using `==` to test the value (instead of `=` to set it).